# Partial fraction expansion two variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

How to expand
$$\frac{y}{(x-y)(y-1)}$$
by partial fraction expansion.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether you view the expression as a function of $x$ or as a function of $y$. If you view it as a function of $x$, the decomposition is already done.

If you view it as a function of $y$, make the usual ansatz:

$$\frac{y}{(x-y)(y-1)} = \frac{A}{x-y} + \frac{B}{y-1}.$$

$A$ and $B$ will depend on  $x$ but not on $y$.

Comment: This will not simplify my problem. Indeed I have the sum $$\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\frac{w_k}{(z-w_k)(w_k-1)}$$where $$w_k=e^{2\pi i k/N}$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT

$$\frac{y}{(x-y)(y-1)} = \frac{Ax+By+C}{x-y} + \frac{Dx+Ey+F}{y-1}$$

Comment: I think there is something wrong, the first term in the last result is  independent of $x$ and $y$ and equals to $1/2$, please check.

Comment: $$\frac{y}{(x-y)(y-1)} = \frac{A}{x-y} + \frac{B}{y-1}$$  
$$A(y-1)+B(x-y)=y$$ $\rightarrow$ $(A-B)y-A+Bx=y$, $A-B=1$ and $Bx-A=0$, i.e.,$A=Bx$  
solving for A and B we get  
$$\frac{y}{(x-y)(y-1)}=\frac{1}{x-1}\left(\frac{1}{y-1}-\frac{x}{y-x}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\text{Plot3D}\left[\left\{\frac{y^4}{(x-1) (y-1)}-\frac{y \left(x^2 y^2+x^2 y+x^2+x y^2+x y+y^2\right)}{x^3},\frac{y}{(y-1) (x-y)},x \left(y+\frac{1}{y}+1\right)+y+1\right\},\{x,-2,2\},\{y,-2,2\},\text{PlotLegends}\to \text{Automatic}\right]$$
use this
$$\frac{y^4}{(x-1) (y-1)}-\frac{y \left(x^2 y^2+x^2 y+x^2+x y^2+x y+y^2\right)}{x^3}$$
[image]
as you can see the orange (above  ) and the blue (your fraction ) are very near is the generalitated laurent series